# Android - WebView refreshing when scrolling or Panning sites like Google Maps

Tags: android, webview, swiperefreshlayout

Hi have been looking into this issue for the last 2 days. I have a web view inside SwipeRefreshLayout which works fine for almost every site but when tried maps.google.com I encountered this weird situation where scrolling the maps triggers SwipeRefresh and the page keeps on reloading().

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. the sample code is below.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var browser: WebView
lateinit var swipeLayout : SwipeRefreshLayout
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     browser = findViewById<View>(R.id.webview) as WebView
    swipeLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout) as SwipeRefreshLayout

    browser.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true;
    browser.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true;
    browser.scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY;

    browser.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/maps");
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
        browser.reload()
        swipeLayout.isRefreshing=false
    }
    browser.webViewClient = (object : WebViewClient() {
       override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
           Log.d("Browser", browser.scrollY.toString())
        }
    })


}
```

The layout file seems like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The gif of the issue is attached below

[image: Issue]

Expected Result: Scrolling Down should only move the maps

Actual Result : SwipeToRefresh is triggered which causes webpage to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: " + view.getUrl());
        //here check the condition
        // if url contains "map" then set swipe layout to setEnabled(false)
        // else setEnabled(true)
        swipelayout.setEnabled(!BASE_URL.concat("my-location").equals(view.getUrl()) && !view.getUrl().contains("running-order"));
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).